# multiplying certain elements of an array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

```
var valid1=[4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8]

function validateCred(array) {
  let doubleArray =0
  for(i=array.length-2; i >= 0; i-=2) {
          doubleArray= array[i]*2
  }
  console.log(doubleArray);      
}

validateCred(valid1)  //prints 8 I want it to print entire loop
```

Im trying to code luhn Algorithm and this is the first step of doubling every second number from the back, i want my result to equal doubleArray however when i try print it only 8 prints

Comment: Change this line ```doubleArray= array[i]*2``` by ```array[i] *= 2``` and finally console the array

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the code below to get the desired output i.e. the an array with doubled value starting from back.

```js
  var valid1=[4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8]

    function validateCred(array) {
       let doubleArray = [];
       for(i=array.length-2; i >= 0; i-=2) {
          doubleArray.push(array[i] * 2)
       }
       return(doubleArray);      
    }

    console.log(validateCred(valid1))
```

Answer (score 0):

you have only 8 prints because you have step `i-2`. Also, see comments in code about reversing an array

```js
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];

function validateCred(array) {
   let doubleArray = [];
   // we should move through all iterations that is why step i-=1
   for(let i = array.length-1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
      // moving from the end of the array we will get reversed copy if using method push()
      // that is why changed to unshift()
      doubleArray.unshift((array.length - 1 - i) % 2 == 0 ? array[i] * 2 : array[i]);
      // array.length - 1 - i - using because we need to move from right in case length not odd
   }
   console.log(doubleArray);
}

// ES6+ syntax version version
function esValidateCred1(array) {
  const doubleArray = array.reverse().map((i, ind) => ind % 2 === 0 ? i*2 : i).reverse();
  console.log(doubleArray);;
}

validateCred(valid1);
esValidateCred1(valid1);
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to use **.map()** method for array

```js
var valid1=[4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8]

function validateCred(array) { 
  return array.map(item => item*2);      
}

console.log( validateCred(valid1) )  //prints array doubled elements
```